# Rename/change cygwin username

Tags: cygwin

When you first start the Cygwin shell, you are logged in as the user you are on Windows. How do you change just the username of that user, leaving the existing cygwin association of the Cygwin user with the Windows user? (i.e. without creating a whole new Windows account)

Why? I just moved over from a virtual machine to Cygwin and wish to reuse all my scripts and shell customizations which assume a specific username (think of .ssh/config, .subversion, etc.) without change.

Comment: The name of my home directory on the present install of Cygwin64 was my full Windows user name, including the space. But it turns out I never used this directory. So my reason for interest in answers to this problem is to avoid having a space in my home path.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My original username was `root` (under Windows, ironically), and I wanted it to be `someuser`. I figured I'd want my home dir to be `/home/someuser` as well, and be readable from Windows.

This is what I did:

```
cd /home
mv root someuser
ln -s someuser root
sed -e 's/^root/someuser/' -e 's/\/home\/root/\/home\/user/' -i /etc/passwd
```

And that's all, just restart the shell.

I made the symlink in case Cygwin updates `/etc/passwd` for some reason, and restores the username to `root` and its home dir to `/home/root`, so that it is still possible to log in.

(To **only** change the username: `sed -e 's/^root/someuser/' -i /etc/passwd`)

Comment: I used this answer and it worked to some extent. Unfortunately the ACL's of the files created under the new directory are wrong in my case. I don't know why that is. If you are considering this answer, consider creating a new account instead, for example consider creating a local account.

Answer (score 26):

For people starting with a clean Cygwin installation an approach might be to create new `/etc/passwd` file (it does not exist per default in current Cygwin versions) using
`mkpasswd -l >/etc/passwd` which will create an entry for every user
(add `-b` to omit the built-in users or just `-c` to only create an entry for the current user, see https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/mkpasswd.html).

Next, simply open `/etc/passwd` rename the account in there (first column).

See https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html for a description of how Cygwin handles the mapping between "Cygwin" and Windows user.
Oh and there is also a `mkgroup` that can be used similarly, see https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/mkgroup.html.

You will see that creating is not officially recommended but from my experience it has not caused any problems, maybe it could if you would do quite advanced stuff involving user/group rights or if you didn't keep it up-to-date when you change the Windows users.

Answer (score 5):

This is what worked for me (Windows 10):

1. `rm /etc/passwd`
2. `mkpasswd -c > /etc/passwd`
3. `ln -s /home/oldname /home/newname`
4. `sed -i 's/oldname/newname/g' /etc/passwd`

Comment: I performed the commands 1, 2, 4. For some reason the ideally-named directory already existed, so I just needed /etc/passwd to enable the right directory.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did that worked on Windows 10 which combines elements of three other answers:

1. Verify your Cygwin /etc/passwd does not exist
2. cd /home
3. mv oldname newname
4. ln -s newname oldname
5. "mkpasswd -l > /etc/passwd" (this will insert many accounts into your new /etc/passwd)
6. sed -i 's/oldname/newname/g' /etc/passwd
7. kill all cygwin shells
8. bring up a new cygwin shell

Comment: `mkpasswd -l > /etc/passwd` creates the file and adds lines to it. But I can't find my user name (oldname) in that file. Nor can I find my "new" user name (newname). I think the proper command to use is `mkpasswd -c > /etc/passwd`.

Comment: @gromit190 I just re-tried the whole 10 step procedure, and although it failed at step 3 when I hadn't finished finalizing something about the install, it worked with even step 5 "mkpasswd -l > /etc/passwd" creating an /etc/passwd where I found my username, and changed it in three places.

Comment: Just re-tried the whole 10 step procedure, and it worked seamlessly.