# Error in building LibreOffice while running ./autogen.sh in cygwin shell

Tags: installation, cygwin, libreoffice

I was following this link to build LibreOffice : https://blog.documentfoundation.org/blog/2019/07/09/start-developing-libreoffice-download-the-source-code-and-build-on-windows/

When I was on the 8th step, I ran ./autogen.sh in the Cygwin shell, it gave the following error :

$src_path must not contain spaces, but it is '$src_path'. (It is the 135th line in the code of autogen.sh)

To remove the error, I removed the spaces in the username which was present at this location - C:\cygwin64\home<username>. It somehow created two usernames inside home, one with spaces and without spaces.
Anyways I continued further because all the required files were present in the username without spaces. I ran ./autogen.sh in the Cygwin shell after going to the right directory (i.e username without spaces)  but then the following error came up :
"cannot find al.exe as /al.exe" (It showed that error is in line 296 of autogen.sh)

I thought I did something wrong and tried to undo the things.

So I again introduced the spaces in the username and it merged the two usernames(It merged the username with spaces and without spaces).

Then I downloaded the raw file of ./autogen.sh from https://github.com/LibreOffice/core/blob/master/autogen.sh
and commented out the 135th line which said "die "$src_path must not contain spaces, but it is '$src_path'." if ($src_path =~ / /)"

Then I again ran ./autogen.sh and it gave the following error :

```
./autogen.sh: line 1: $':\r': command not found
aclocal-1.16: error: non-option arguments are not accepted: 'Khare/libreoffice/m4'.
aclocal-1.16: Try '/usr/bin/aclocal-1.16 --help' for more information.
Failed to run aclocal at ./autogen.sh line 196.
```

I am stuck. Someone please help.

Comment: Can you share some specific code you've tried?

Comment: It is a very bad idea to have spaces in any directory or file name under cygwin. It leads to endless problems. Make sure your cygwin user name has no spaces in it. If you want, you can have spaces in your windows user name and directories and files, but you will still have to be careful to quote those file names and paths, or a lot of windows development tools will break the file names into two pieces at each space. I don't know what you mean by removed the spaces in username and directories. Just delete the user with spaces in name, and recreate a user without spaces. Then start over.

Comment: I removed spaces in the username and did it all again. 
It now gives the following error on running ./autogen.sh in the Cygwin shell :

checking for al.exe... configure: error: al.exe not found as /al.exe
Error running configure at ./autogen.sh line 299.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed spaces from Cygwin user name following this:

[Rename/change cygwin username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19613654/rename-change-cygwin-username)

And it solved the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks  @Doug Henderson for the suggestion.